# How to get the # of options with the attr "selected" in a drop down using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This isn't working for me:

```
    $('select').each(function() {  

        alert($(this).find('option').attr('selected').length);

    }
```

actually what I really need is to just detect if the present select has any preselected options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector:

```
alert($(this).find("option:selected").length);
```

Or, alternately, using `this` as the selector's context:

```
alert($("option:selected", this).length);
```